# Python scraping fetech href links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to fetch Art and Biography from below href link

```
<a class="gr-hyperlink" href="/genres/art">Art</a>,
 <a class="gr-hyperlink" href="/genres/biography">Biography</a>,
```

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def getHTMLContent(link):
    html = urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    return soup

content = getHTMLContent('https://abc')
hyperLinks = content.find_all('a', class_="gr-hyperlink")
hyperLinks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After running `find_all` on a `BeautifulSoup` element, you get an iterable `ResultSet` element.
2. Each item in the `ResultSet` is a BeautifulSoup `Tag` element.

Use BeautifulSoup's `get_text` method to extract the `Tag`'s text:

```py
content = [link.get_text() for link in hyperLinks]
```